# Перенос grub на другой диск

Tags: linux, windows, debian, grub, boot

Имеется ноутбук с родным HDD на 500гб, так же установлен ssd на 120. На ssd стоит win7 на одном из разделов hdd стоит debian, и соответственно grub, который исправно работает несколько лет. HDD потихоньку доживает свое и скоро будет заменен. При отключении HDD grub запускается только в режиме консоли и не дает запустить win7 с ssd. win7 установлена в sda1, debian полагаю в sdb. Нужно перенести grub полностью на ssd. команда:

> grub-install dev/sda/

говорит о секторе 32 и установленном туда FlexNet, ну и об отсутствии ошибок тоже. Но по прежнему не запускается при отсоединении HDD. Что делать?

Comment: *Нужно перенести grub полностью на ssd* — только вместе с файловой системой, где, собственно, и располается grub. в mbr (или перед первым разделом) или на gpt-разделе находится лишь мизерная, стартовая часть загрузчика. остальное необходимое — в файлах внутри файловой системы (обычно в каталоге `/boot/grub`)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй использовать опцию recheck

> grub-install --recheck

обычно помогает